# Calculations based on condition in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, conditional-statements, psql

I am having trouble doing calculations in one table using conditional statements. I have a table 'df' with the following column names:

- id - int
- time - timestamp
- correctness - boolean
- subject - text

Every student (id) completes tasks on particular subject (subject). The system assigns "True" value in column "correctness" if the assignment is completed correctly and "False" if not. The time (time) when the student completes the task is also saved by the system.

I need to write an optimal sql query that counts all students who completed 20 tasks successfully within an hour during March 2020.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Still unsolved!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with no subqueries using:

```
select distinct s.id
from t
where t.timestamp >= '2020-03-01' and t.timestamp < '2020-04-01'
group by s.id, date_trunc('hour', timestamp)
having count(*) >= 20;
```

Note:  You may want that the tasks are completed *successfully*, but that is not actually mentioned in your question.

For performance, you want an index on `(timestamp)`.

Comment: Thank you but I need to count those who completed the tasks during the hour from the actual time they started and actual time the finished. 'Date_trunc' does not provide for this

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at each 'correct' task and see if there are 20 previous tasks, delivered within one hour, that are correct.

That means you have to inner join task unto itself and then count them.

```
select distinct on(tasks.id) tasks.id, tasks.time, sum(previous_tasks.id)
from tasks
inner join tasks previous_tasks
    on tasks.id = previous_tasks.id
         and (previous_tasks.time - tasks.time) < interval '1 hour'
         and previous_tasks.correctness
         and tasks.time >= '2020-03-01' and tasks.time < '2020-04-01'
         and previous_tasks.time >= '2020-03-01' and previous_tasks.time < '2020-04-01'
group by 1, 2
having sum(previous_tasks.id) >= 20
```

Comment: I don't have task_id's